# How can I most simply automate an Oracle query in windows?

Tags: sql, windows, oracle, shell, sqlcl

I need to run the same damn Oracle query daily (and export the output, which I can do from the sql file itself). I'd like to automate using Windows Task Scheduler but it only opens the script, and it doesn't run it.

Is this feasible or is there an easier way?

Comment: What is the the command you are running. Assuming you are running something like  `sqlcl un/pw@db @the_script.sql`  and it is not running the sql in the script, is the SQL statment in teh script terminated by a `;` or `/`?

Comment: First check if you are able to make connection to database. Then we can debug why query is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description isn't very *descriptive* (we don't know how exactly you did that), but - here's a suggestion:

- create a .bat script (let's call it `a.bat`) which will call your .sql (let's call it `a.sql`) script. Only one line in it:

  ```
  sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl @a.sql
  ```
- `a.sql` is ... well, what it is, for example

  ```
  prompt Number of rows in EMP table

  select count(*) from emp;
  ```

Create a job in Task Scheduler which will start a program (`a.bat`).

I've just tried it (using that simple example I posted above) and got the result (saying that there are 14 rows in the table), so I hope you'll get it as well.